# Separate JavaScript positive and negative numbers

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me to find the error? My main target is when we enter  an array to give the result same as the below I showed, Input

```
{-5, -4, 10, 12, 13, 4, 5, -8, -6}
```

output

```
{10, 12, 13, 4, 5, -5, -4, -8, -6}
```

Here I attached my full code. I don't get outputs.

[image]

```js
function foo() {
  var arrch = document.getElementById("text").value.spilt(" ").map(Number);
  var dlina = arrch.length;
  var new_arr = [];
  var new_arr2 = [];
  var k = 0;
  var summa = 0;
  var n = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < dlina; i++) {
    if (arrch[i] > 0) {
      summa += arrch[i];
      new_arr[n] = arrch[i];
      n++;
    } else if (arrch[i] < 0) {
      new_arr2[k] = arrch[i];
      k++;
    }
  }
  new_arr = new_arr.join(" ");
  new_arr2 = new_arr2.join(" ");

  document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = new_arr + " " + new_arr2;
  document.getElementById("text3").innerHTML = summa;
}
```

```html
<H3>RK1</H3>
<form>
  <p>Enter Array</p>
  <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter Text"><br>
  <p>Changed array</p>
  <p id="text2"></p>
  <p>plus Array</p>
  <p id="text3"></p>
  <button onclick="foo()">Give Answer</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `<form.submit()>` <-- That is not valid HTML nor JavaScript.

Comment: `.innerHTML` <-- You should use `.textContent` or `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`, as you'll open yourself up to an XSS vuln.

Comment: There's a typo in the name of the `split` function. https://jsfiddle.net/efortis/zq6ysnf4/

Comment: @EricFortis well, no use crying over split milk :)

Comment: why `-6` is changed to `+6` ?

Comment: of course addition is commutative, so I'm assuming this is just a display question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to sort the negative numbers to the end of the array, you can [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) based on the sign of the numbers. You can sum the array using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const arr = [-5,-4,10,12,13,4,5,-8,-6]

arr.sort((a, b) => Math.sign(b) - Math.sign(a))

console.log(arr)

const sum = arr.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el)

console.log(sum)
```

Here's a modified version of your code with those changes (and the typo in `split` noted by @EricFortis corrected):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--
        Positive Numbers one side and negetive numbers other side
      -->
  <title>RK1</title>
</head>

<body>
  <H3>RK1</H3>
  <form>
    <p>Enter Array</p>
    <input type="text" id="text" placeholder="Enter Text"><br>
    <p>Changed array</p>
    <p id="text2"></p>
    <p>plus Array</p>
    <p id="text3"></p>
    <button onclick="foo(event)">Give Answer</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function foo(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var arrch = document.getElementById("text").value.split(" ").map(Number);
        arrch.sort((a, b) => Math.sign(b) - Math.sign(a))
        var summa = arrch.reduce((acc, el) => acc + el)

        document.getElementById("text2").innerText = arrch;
        document.getElementById("text3").innerText = summa;
      }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can code that this way...

```js
const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form')

myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault() 
  let res = myForm.txtNums.value
    .match(/([-+]?\d+)/g).map(Number)
    .reduce((r,n) =>
      {
      r[(n<0?'neg':'pos')].push(n)
      r.sum += n
      return r 
      }
      ,{sum:0,pos:[],neg:[]}
    ) 
  myForm.txtOut_1.textContent = `{${res.pos.concat(res.neg).join(',')}}`
  myForm.txtOut_2.textContent = res.sum
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
}
label {
  display   : block;
  font-size : .8rem;
  padding   : .4rem .2rem;
  }
input,
output {
  display   : block;
  border    : 1px solid lightslategrey;
  width     : 16rem;
  font-size : 1rem;
  padding   : .2rem .4em;
  }
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <label>Enter Array
    <input type="text" name="txtNums"
           placeholder="Enter Text"
           value="{-5,-4,10,12,13,4,5,-8,-6}">
  </label>  
  <label>Changed array 
    <output name="txtOut_1">.</output>
  </label> 
  <label>plus Array
    <output name="txtOut_2">.</output>
  </label> 
  <button>Give Answer</button>
</form>
```